# How to send string data to UIButton tag?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is there any way of sending string value to `UIButton` tag? I know `tag` is **Int** type but I need to send **string** value.

```
let myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.tag = "123"
    return button
}()
```

I need to send `button.tag` as a string

Comment: Use the `accessibilityIdentifier` property instead.

Comment: The data type of the `tag` property is `Int` (it's defined on `UIView` and inherited by `UIButton`). You cannot change the data type, hence it's not possible to assign a string to that property. If you can give more detail about what you want to achieve, there may be a chance that someone can help you with a possible solution to your problem - but as I said, the short answer to your question is _no_.

Comment: accessibilityIndetifier helped me thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom class of UIButton and create one `String` type property like `customTag`

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var customTag:String = ""
}
```

Assign the custom class to your UIButton and use String type tag by following code.

```
let myButton: CustomButton = {
    let button = CustomButton()
    button.customTag = "ABC"
    return button
}()
```

Comment: thanks but I used accessibilityLabel for string in UIButton

Comment: Okay, not an issue, but this way you can add one or more custom property(variable) of UIButton.

Comment: (mis) using accessibility label is not a good idea. That will screw up VoiceOver for vision-impaired users (VoiceOver will speak the text you put into the accessibility label.)

Comment: The accessibility identifier is also not great, since that is used for AppleUI testing. If you don't have any AppleUI tests then that won't affect you, but it would cause problems if you develop UI tests later.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of tag you can do it using `accessibilityLabel`.

```
btn.accessibilityLabel = "ABC"
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

One more answer.

Instead of `accessibilityLabel` / `accessibilityIdentifier` or any other related to `accessibility` , let us go for `layer.name`

```
Button.layer.name = "abc123"

@IBAction func wasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print("was Pressed     \(sender.layer.name)")
}
```

**Reason:**

Incase, we are in need to set accessibility for each and every screen, at that time it might affect.

But, if we are in need to add another layer for `UIButton`, it will not affect

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, the tag is just an integer value.
What you could do is:

- Subclass `UIButton` and add your own property
- Use associated objects, like in https://gist.github.com/mjjimenez/7956352
- Use enums for the tag; maybe add an extension to access them
- (Mis)use the `accessibilityIdentifier`

Answer (score 1):

Just create `extension` of `UIButton` or `NSObject`.

```
extension NSObject {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var DescriptiveName = "strCustomTag"
    }

    var strCustomTag: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.DescriptiveName) as? String
        }

        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(
                    self,
                    &AssociatedKeys.DescriptiveName,
                    newValue as NSString?,
                    .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Refer below code to set the value of `strCustomTag`**

```
let myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.strCustomTag = "ABC"
    return button
}()
```

**Get Value**

```
print(view.strCustomTag)
```

> **If you create an `extension` of `NSObject`**
>
> `strCustomTag` is accessible from any class or any UI Elements such as
>   `UIButton`, `UITextField`, `UIView` etc.
>
> No need to change in exsting `storyboard` OR `XIB` file

Comment: Thanks accessibilityLabel helped me

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the tag to String because its type is Int.

Most probably you will no need to set it anyway because using the tag of UIView is not a common technique.

If you still want to use similar solution (I recommend not to) then you may use the `accessibilityIdentifier` property which is String.

Also you can create a custom subclass of UIButton with custom String property and to use this custom subclass instead of UIButton

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom class for button then you can pass any kind of values by just define the property in the custom class.

Example: I want to pass the String and Int both values in Button So I will pass Int in to button tag and string will be passed in custom button property.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var stringToPass: String = ""
}
```

ViewController Class

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    let customButton = CustomButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customButton.stringToPass = "Your String"
    }
}
```